# Did Grimm's law take effect only 2500 years ago?

Tags: proto-germanic, grimms-law

Some of the indo-european languages* are documented to be up to 3800 years old, like Hethitic, or 3600 years for Greek. So one would expect that the others are not substantially younger. (* I refer to the proto languages that followed proto IE, like proto Germanic, proto Celtic and so on.)

Now there seems to be a hypothesis that proto Germanic could be as "young" as only 2500 years, which is based on some "facts" concerning the dating of Grimm's law. As far as I found out myself so far, it deals with:

1. a few names in latin texts (like *Vahalis* for the river *Waal*), but those are questionable because Latin had no letters for fricatives.
2. a few names in Germanic (like *welsh* from the celtic tribe of the *Volcae*), but there are no clues when those entered the germanic vocabulary.
3. the "hemp-hypothesis" (Barber 1991) that germanic **hanapiz* was not inherited from proto indo-european but instead is a loanword from Cimmerian from the mid 1st millenium BC. But this hypothesis violates Occam's razor and raises several questions.

I'd like to dig deeper into those things, maybe someone can point me to the right publications.

Comment: this has been answered before. here under the relevant tags or on reddit, e.g. r/badling, r/indoeuropean, I don't quite remember. short answer: yes, as you said, if words were loaned from Latin, show effects of Grimm's law, and can by arcaeological and historical evidence not be assumed to have been needed in Germanic any sooner. That's just the argument I remember, there might be more, and I'm not fully convinced of it, that proto-germanic was monolithic, that the reconstructions are sound (good, but far from perfectl), that there were few changes  before that for hundreds of years.

Comment: if *kannabis* is not compared to *kanna*, I canna really not have any hope in this field, or at least not in myself to ever achieve the level of rigor mortis needed to not conflate pairs like this. Like, you cannot not move--panta rhei, banners fly, borders move, hunters cry.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding in your first paragraph. The fact that Hittite and Greek are documented in the second millennium BC doesn't imply that all other IE languages should be dated to the same period -- would you expect that English should be "not substantially younger"? Proto-Germanic is just a name for one of the stages between PIE and English.

Comment: @TKR: I corrected that now to make it clearer what I mean (the "post proto-IE proto-languages", of course not English/Portuguese/Russian/...).

Comment: The point is that the "post proto-IE proto-languages" is not a meaningfully defined set that can be expected to have anything in common. A proto-language is just a (reconstructed) language. Our understanding of the branching of IE depends largely on accidents of historical preservation; there's no reason to expect that the top nodes of what we happen to know of that tree should be contemporaneous with each other.

Comment: If one thinks of PIE as a loose assemblage of semi-nomadic dialects represented by random samples over several millennia of Asian prehistory, it doesn't give one the same impression as carbon-dating. There were always plenty of differences among groups, as there always are, and plenty of opportunities to differ more profitably. A millennium is a **long** time; several millennia is almost inconceivable. That's 30 to 40 generations. Nothing stays the same that long, and it was never "the same" to start with.

Comment: @TKR: On the other hand we do know from historic time how such processes take place, for example the expansion of Slavic or Germanic: there is a time frame of migration, followed by a consolidation phase that results into the successor languages. So I think it is justified to suppose that the "post proto-IE proto-languages" are of approximately the same age, or at least not 1000 years apart.

Comment: Migration is a constant in human history. There's no reason to assume all the migrations that gave rise to IE branches happened at the same time -- *a priori* that's very unlikely. PIE speakers didn't split neatly into ten groups one morning and each wander off in a different direction.

Comment: Also consider that the reason we know much more about the early history of Greek and Hittite than about that of the Germanic languages is simply that writing happens to have been used in the Mediterranean region much earlier than in western/northern Europe. If whatever IE speakers lived in NW Europe in 1800 BC had used writing, our IE tree would look different and we wouldn't think of Proto-Germanic as being one of the "first nodes down" from PIE.

Comment: @TKR: That's the way languages expand and fall apart. For example, the slavic languages all emerged after the expansion of proto-slavic, no need for different phases of migration for different slavic languages. There's always this cycle of expansion-consolidation-conservation.

Comment: @TKR: On the other hand, if we suppose that proto Germanic is not that old, not many changes on the consonant level are left for the "pre-proto-germanic" level. Grimm's law seems to be _the_ most important difference to proto IE. The vocalic features seem to be even younger.

Comment: There are lots of other important differences between PG and PIE, e.g. Verner's Law, fixed initial stress, *o/*a merger and other vowel changes, massive simplification of the verb system, "weak verbs", etc.

Comment: It's not true that "the slavic languages all emerged after the expansion of proto-slavic" -- there are subfamilies within Slavic resulting from later splits (South Slavic vs. West and East). There are similar splits within Germanic, and presumably there were similar splits we don't know about en route from PIE to PG. No one thinks that all the proto-languages of the primary IE branches were contemporaneous.

Comment: (To give a concrete example, Italic and Celtic are IE families, but some people believe their last common ancestor was PIE, and others believe their last common ancestor was a later Proto-Italo-Celtic. In both cases the chronology works out.)

Comment: I think anyone going with #3 is probably smoking **hanapiz*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, **by definition**, proto-Germanic is the reconstructed ancestor of all attested Germanic languages. Since the Germanic languages are really closely related, and their attestation does not go back very far in time, it is no surprise that proto-Germanic is rather young.

Another problem is dating sound laws. AFAIK, there is still an ongoing debate whether Grimm's law or Verner's law happened first. And this is just about the relative order of sound laws.

Giving absolute dates is even more difficult and is usually done by judging loan words to and from Germanic languages. Because words like *Keller* "cellar" and *Kaiser* "emperor" are not touched by Grimm's law we can conclude that it was no longer active in the 1st century BCE. I have no good arguments for the earliest onset of Grimm's law, but I think that 5th c. BCE is the consensus in the community.